# set a selected button in DLRadioButton

Tags: swift, xcode, button, tags, dlradiobutton

I used DLRadioButton and I want to set one of the buttons selected by the value that I was retrieved from the DataBase ready, but I can change just the fires button because I can't determination the tag number

I want the button that has tag 2 be selected

```
   if editgender == "Girl"{ GenderButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "Picture2.png"), for: .normal);}
```

Comment: What is your return from the database? Also, I didn’t really understand your code example. Can you paste the entire implementation? (Use the ` char to format as code)

Comment: @alxlives sorry I edit my question the value editgender I saved on it  data comes from the database if the data is "Girl" the button of tag 2 is must be selected. if the data is "Boy" the button with tag 1 must be selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the button via tag using `viewWithTag(tag)`.

Just tested this code and it works as expected:

```swift
   let buttonTag = editgender == "Girl" ? 2 : 1

   let genderButton = self.view.viewWithTag(buttonTag) as? DLRadioButton
   genderButton?.setImage(UIImage(named: "Picture2.png"), for: .normal)
```